# Compiler error: could not find member 'subscript' with &&

Tags: swift, xcode6, subscript

```
 var card:[[Int]] = bank[numberOfMarked].card;

  if ((card[0][0] == 0) && (card[1][1] == 0) && (card[2][2] == 0) && (card[3][3] == 0) && (card[4][4] == 0))
    {
     return true; 
    }
```

i am getting the error "Could not find member 'subscript' and the compiler is pointing to the last &&.

Comment: We'll need a little more context than that. For one thing, how is `card` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I'd [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/) -- I'm getting this error as well: `note: expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`. Nothing wrong with that expression, but to use it in Swift right now you'll need to break it up into a couple `Bool` variables:

```
let firstTwo = card[0][0] == 0 && card[1][1] == 0
let lastThree = card[2][2] == 0 && card[3][3] == 0 && card[4][4] == 0
if firstTwo && lastThree {
    return true
}
```